# code don't work on my d18b20 temperature sensor

Tags: arduino

The simple code for arduino is down the page and everything works (it shows me temperature as it is), but in this example I include ethernet and begin internet and it doesn't show me temperature anymore....in serial monitor it just shows me temperature -127.00, so it mean it doesn't work. I am very new at programming, so I am sorta noob and maybe it's some banal question and answer, but I don't get it, why I cant start ethernet in setup function. I only need that for my other project which will include mqtt, so I will need ethernet. Please help and thanks for answers.

```cpp
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Data wire is plugged into pin 12 on the Arduino
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 12
// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices (not just Maxim/Dallas temperature ICs)
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature. 
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

byte mac[]    = {  0xDE, 0xED, 0xBA, 0xFE, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 80);


void setup(void)
{ 
Serial.begin(9600); //Begin serial communication
Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
Serial.println("Arduino Digital Temperature // Serial Monitor Version"); //Print a message
sensors.begin();
}

void loop(void)
{ 
// Send the command to get temperatures
sensors.requestTemperatures();  
Serial.print("Temperature is: ");
Serial.println(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0)); // Why "byIndex"? You can have more than one IC on the same bus. 0 refers to the first IC on the wire
//Update value every 1 sec.
delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Your question is **unclear**, please read this: [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ethernet uses pin 12, as does your temp sensor; that's no good...

Comment: tnx for the answer. that was my problem yes. I changed pin and now all works as charm. tnx alot!